# How is HDF5 different from a folder with files?

Tags: python, persistence, metadata, hdf5

I'm working on an [open source project](https://github.com/abstractfactory/openmetadata) dealing with adding metadata to folders. The provided (Python) API lets you browse and access metadata like it was just another folder. Because it is just another folder.

```
\folder\.meta\folder\somedata.json
```

Then I came across [HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/) and its derivation [Alembic](http://www.alembic.io/).

Reading up on HDF5 in the book [Python and HDF5](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920030249.do) I was looking for benefits to using it compared to using files in folders, but most of what I came across spoke about the benefits of a hierarchical file-format in terms of its simplicity in adding data via its API:

```
>>> import h5py
>>> f = h5py.File("weather.hdf5")
>>> f["/15/temperature"] = 21
```

Or its ability to read only certain parts of it upon request (e.g. random access), and parallel execution of a single HDF5 file (e.g. for multiprocessing)

You could mount HDF5 files, https://github.com/zjttoefs/hdfuse5

It even boasts a strong yet simple foundation concept of **Groups** and **Datasets** which from wiki reads:

- Datasets, which are multidimensional arrays of a homogeneous type
- Groups, which are container structures which can hold datasets and
  other groups

Replace **Dataset** with **File** and **Group** with **Folder** and the whole feature-set sounds to me like what files in folders are already fully capable of doing.

For every benefit I came across, not one stood out as being exclusive to HDF5.

So my question is, if I were to give you one HDF5 file and one folder with files, both with identical content, in which scenario would HDF5 be better suited?

Edit:

Having gotten some responses about the portability of HDF5.

It sounds lovely and all, but I still haven't been given an example, a scenario, in which an HDF5 would out-do a folder with files. Why would someone consider using HDF5 when a folder is readable on any computer, any file-system, over a network, supports "parallel I/O", is readable by humans without an HDF5 interpreter.

I would go as far as to say, a folder with files is far more portable than any HDF5.

Edit 2:

Thucydides411 just gave an example of a scenario where portability matters.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28512028/478949

I think what I'm taking away from the answers in this thread is that HDF5 is well suited for when you need the organisational structure of files and folders, like in the example scenario above, with lots (millions) small (~1 byte) data structures; like individual numbers or strings. That it makes up for what file-systems lack by providing a "sub file-system" favouring the small and many as opposed to few and large.

In computer graphics, we use it to store geometric models and arbitrary data about individual vertices which seems to align quite well with it's use in the scientific community.

Comment: I'm sort of curious about the followup question: instead of comparing with text based or non-portable formats which is a bit of a strawman, I'm also curious about why one would pick HDF5 when the files in the folders may be in other "good" file formats like Parquet?

Answer (score 89):

As someone who developed a scientific project that went from using folders of files to HDF5, I think I can shed some light on the advantages of HDF5.

When I began my project, I was operating on small test datasets, and producing small amounts of output, in the range of kilobytes. I began with the easiest data format, tables encoded as ASCII. For each object I processed, I produced on ASCII table.

I began applying my code to groups of objects, which meant writing multiple ASCII tables at the end of each run, along with an additional ASCII table containing output related to the entire group. For each group, I now had a folder that looked like:

```
+ group
|    |-- object 1
|    |-- object 2
|    |-- ...
|    |-- object N
|    |-- summary
```

At this point, I began running into my first difficulties. ASCII files are very slow to read and write, and they don't pack numeric information very efficiently, because each digit takes a full Byte to encode, rather than ~3.3 bits. So I switched over to writing each object as a custom binary file, which sped up I/O and decreased file size.

As I scaled up to processing large numbers (tens of thousands to millions) of groups, I suddenly found myself dealing with an extremely large number of files and folders. Having too many small files can be a problem for many filesystems (many filesystems are limited in the number of files they can store, regardless of how much disk space there is). I also began to find that when I would try to do post-processing on my entire dataset, the disk I/O to read many small files was starting to take up an appreciable amount of time. I tried to solve these problems by consolidating my files, so that I only produced two files for each group:

```
+ group 1
|    |-- objects
|    |-- summary
+ group 2
|    |-- objects
|    |-- summary
...
```

I also wanted to compress my data, so I began creating .tar.gz files for  collections of groups.

At this point, my whole data scheme was getting very cumbersome, and there was a risk that if I wanted to hand my data to someone else, it would take a lot of effort to explain to them how to use it. The binary files that contained the objects, for example, had their own internal structure that existed only in a README file in a repository and on a pad of paper in my office. Whoever wanted to read one of my combined object binary files would have to know the byte offset, type and endianness of each metadata entry in the header, and the byte offset of every object in the file. If they didn't, the file would be gibberish to them.

The way I was grouping and compressing data also posed problems. Let's say I wanted to find one object. I would have to locate the .tar.gz file it was in, unzip the entire contents of the archive to a temporary folder, navigate to the group I was interested in, and retrieve the object with my own custom API to read my binary files. After I was done, I would delete the temporarily unzipped files. It was not an elegant solution.

At this point, I decided to switch to a standard format. HDF5 was attractive for a number of reasons. Firstly, I could keep the overall organization of my data into groups, object datasets and summary datasets. Secondly, I could ditch my custom binary file I/O API, and just use a multidimensional array dataset to store all the objects in a group. I could even create arrays of more complicated datatypes, like arrays of `C` structs, without having to meticulously document the byte offsets of every entry. Next, HDF5 has chunked compression which can be completely transparent to the end user of the data. Because the compression is chunked, if I think users are going to want to look at individual objects, I can have each object compressed in a separate chunk, so that only the part of the dataset the user is interested in needs to be decompressed. Chunked compression is an extremely powerful feature.

Finally, I can just give a single file to someone now, without having to explain much about how it's internally organized. The end user can read the file in Python, C, Fortran, or `h5ls` on the commandline or the GUI HDFView, and see what's inside. That wasn't possible with my custom binary format, not to mention my .tar.gz collections.

Sure, it's possible to replicate everything you can do with HDF5 with folders, ASCII and custom binary files. That's what I originally did, but it became a major headache, and in the end, HDF5 did everything I was kluging together in an efficient and portable way.

Comment: Very interesting indeed; +1

Comment: just curious, if you had to retrieve almost all the data items, lets say an array of 100k in size every few mins, modify it in some way and write it back, do you think hdf5 is suitable, reading wise gotta read everything but upsert would be say 5% of the data set at max

Comment: Do you think SQLite or postgres with occasional blobs would be viable alternatives as well, or HDF5 still suits better for the problem?

Answer (score 12):

Thanks for asking this interesting question. Is a folder with files portable because I can copy a directory onto a stick on a Mac and then see the same directory and files on a PC? I agree that the file directory structure is portable, thanks to the people that write operating systems, but this is unrelated to the data in the files being portable. Now, if the files in this directory are pdf's, they are portable because there are tools that read and make sense of pdfs in multiple operating systems (thanks to Adobe). But, if those files are raw scientific data (in ASCII or binary doesn't matter) they are not at all portable. The ASCII file would look like a bunch of characters and the binary file would look like gibberish. If the were XML or json files, they would be readable, because json is ASCII, but the information they contain would likely not be portable because the meaning of the XML/json tags may not be clear to someone that did not write the file. This is an important point, the characters in an ASCII file are portable, but the information they represent is not.

HDF5 data are portable, just like the pdf, because there are tools in many operating systems that can read the data in HDF5 files (just like pdf readers, see http://www.hdfgroup.org/products/hdf5_tools/index.html). There are also libraries in many languages that can be used to read the data and present it in a way that makes sense to users – which is what Adobe reader does. There are hundreds of groups in the HDF5 community that do the same thing for their users (see http://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/users5.html).

There has been some discussion here of compression as well. The important thing about compressing in HDF5 files is that objects are compressed independently and only the objects that you need get decompressed on output. This is clearly more efficient than compressing the entire file and having to decompress the entire file to read it.

The other critical piece is that HDF5 files are self-describing – so, people that write the files can add information that helps users and tools know what is in the file. What are the variables, what are their types, what software wrote them, what instruments collected them, etc. It sounds like the tool you are working on can read metadata for files. Attributes in an HDF5 file can be attached to any object in the file – they are not just file level information. This is huge. And, of course, those, attributes can be read using tools written in many languages and many operating systems.

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently evaluating HDF5 so had the same question.

This article – [Moving Away from HDF5](http://cyrille.rossant.net/moving-away-hdf5/) – asks pretty much the same question. The article raises some good points about the fact that there is only a single implementation of the HDF5 library which is developed in relatively opaque circumstances by modern open-source standards.

As you can tell from the title, the authors decided to move away from HDF5, to a filesystem hierarchy of binary files containing arrays with metadata in JSON files. This was in spite having made a significant investment in HDF5, having had their fingers burnt by data corruption and performance issues.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.

Answer (score 2):

I think the main advantage is **portability**.

HDF5 stores information about your datasets like the size, type and endianness of integers and floating point numbers, which means you can move an hdf5 file around and read its content even if it was created on a machine with a different architecture.

You can also attach arbitrary metadata to groups and datasets. Arguably you can also do that with files and folders if your filesystem support extended attributes.

An hdf5 file is a single file which can sometimes be more convenient than having to zip/tar folders and files. There is also a major drawback to this: if you delete a dataset, you can't reclaim the space without creating a new file.

Generally, HDF5 is well suited for storing large arrays of numbers, typically scientific datasets.

Comment: In a response from the developers of HDF5, this was their main argument too. But I still can't see how an HDF5 file is any more portable than any folder with one or more files inside; e.g. plain text, JSON, binary; metadata could easily be stored in any of these.

Comment: **Plain text** (JSON, XML…) is very portable (encoding issues aside) but **binary** is not. For instance, if you write an array of numbers in a file using `fwrite` (in C) on a computer, move the file to an other computer with a different architecture and try to read it with `fread`, it won't work as expected.

Comment: Compress a JSON and you have yourself a binary. I'm not seeing how containers play any part in portability.

Comment: Let's say you want to store a 4 bytes integer on disk. You need a 4 bytes file, right? Now if you were to move this 4 bytes file to a different computer and load the number, you might end up with a different number. The reason is that the bytes might be ordered differently. So in fact, for your (binary) file to be portable, it needs to have a few more bits to store information about byte ordering (metadata). HDF5 does this for you.

Comment: I think this goes hand in hand with what innoSPG was saying about an api exposing a common interface for similar data. Storing 4 bytes independently, which is a common use case for my application of something like hdf5, would require consistency.

Answer (score 2):

To me, we can compare folder with files to HDF5 only in the relevant context of scientific data where the most important data are arrays described by a set of metadata.

In the general context, Marcus is alright when he claims that folder with files is far more portable than any HDF5. I will add that in a general context, a folder with file is far most accessible than a HDF5 file. The obvious challenge is that with "normal" folder and files, there is no need of an extra API to access data. That is simply impossible with HDF5 that keeps data and metadata in the same file.

Imagine a moment, to read your pdf file, you need a new pdf reader that understands HDF5? Imagine, to play your music, you need a music player that can decode HDF5? to run your python script, the python interpreter needs to first decode the HDF5? Or the total, to launch your python interpreter, your operating system needs to decode the HDF5? etc. I will have simply not be able to write this answer, because my OS won't have been able to launch my web browser, that won't have able to read its internal files because I previously 
turned everything into HDF5 (maybe a large HDF5 for everything in my hard drive).

Storing meta data in separate file has that huge advantage of working well with the huge amount of data files and softwares that already exist without any extra piece of headache.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is somewhat what I'm thinking. But I'm still waiting to see this "scientific data" that fits so much better within an HDF5. HDF5 really doesn't seem like anything else than a re-invention of a file-system that can be put on a file-system. A file-system is a fantastic invention and surprisingly undervalued. Not until someone puts it in a file do people start to appreciate its potential.

Comment: Even in the context of scientific data, to my point of view, the main relevance of HDF5 is the availability of APIs that allows the use of data independently of the language, in addition to the portability. I use NetCDF everyday in my work. I like the fact that I create a data file with metadata in few lines of code from fortran and access it easily from python, and even get a collaborator update it easily from its own program without complaining. But I am not ready to put my fortran code or compiler in a HDF5 file. The day you provide multilanguage API to your system, I will shift to it.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. An api for metadata and storage of plain-old-datatypes. Files and folders may be portable, but they share no common interface for accessing similar data such as numbers. Good point, thanks for this.

Answer (score 2):

A game where you need to load a lot of resources into the memory would be a scenario in which an HDF5 may be better than a folder with files. Loading data from files has costs as seek time, the time required to open each file, and read data from the file into memory. These operations can be even slower when reading data from a DVD or Blu-ray. Opening a single file can reduce drastically those costs.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this sounds likely but have you run any benchmarks? I'd imagine HDF5 also having its toll on seek due to being able to randomly access elements within, along with the transparent compression/decompression mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't run any benchmarks yet. You have a point there, but I think it's unlikely a randomly access be faster in a disk than in memory.

Comment: Well, they would both be randomly accessing from disk. For example, let's say we're talking about a 128gb dataset. If the data was in a HDF5, it wouldn't be loaded into memory before being read, but rather read from disk as-is; much like it would if it were instead files and folders.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the main advantage is that HDF5 is portable.  HDF5 files can be accessed by a host of other programming/interpreting languages, such as Python (which your API is built on), MATLAB, Fortran and C. As Simon suggested, HDF5 is used extensively in the scientific community to store large datasets.  In my experience, I find the ability to retrieve only certain datasets (and regions) useful.  In addition, the building the HDF5 library for parallel I/O is very advantageous for post-processing of raw data at a later time.

Since the file is also self-describing, it is capable of storing not just raw data, but also description of that data, such as the array size, array name, units and a host of additional metadata.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Accessing only certain parts of an HDF5 without having to load it all. This is certainly a great feature, but no more so then what is already possibly with a folder with files. Parallel I/O comes down to reading more than one file and "self-describing" to storing metadata within the folder as a file - take for example the .DS_Store of OSX.

Answer (score 0):

HDF5 is ultimately, a format to store numbers, optimised for large datasets. The main strengths are the support for compression (that can make reading and writing data faster in many circumstances) and the fast in-kernel queries (retrieval of data fulfilling certain conditions, for example, all the values of pressure when the temperature was over 30 C).

The fact that you can combine several datasets in the same file is just a convenience. For example, you could have several groups corresponding to different weather stations, and each group consisting on several tables of data. For each group you would have a set of attributes describing the details of the instruments, and each table the individual settings. You can have one h5 file for each block of data, with an attribute in the corresponding place and it would give you the same functionality. But now, what you can do with HDF5 is to repack the file for optimized querying, compress the whole thing slightly, and retrieve your information at a blazing speed. If you have several files, each one would be individually compressed, and the OS would decide the layout on disk, that may not be the optimal.

One last thing HDF5 allows you is to load a file (or a piece) in memory exposing the same API as in disk. So, for example, you could use one or other backend depending on the size of the data and the available RAM. In your case, that would be equivalent as copying the relevant information to /dev/shm in Linux, and you would be responsible for commiting back to disk any modification.

Comment: Compression, I don't buy. Compression on any file have existed far longer than HDF5 and I can't imagine that HDF5 offers anything better in that regard. If it did, it would be available to non-hdf5 files too. "in-kernel queries" however, now that's interesting! I'll have to look in to that one as it resembles - if I understand you correctly - what is commonly offered by databases and SQL queries.

Comment: As for loading a hdf5 file or chunks of if into memory with an exposed api for just that chunk, would I really have to make copies? Couldn't I utilise sym- or hard-links? Symlinking could potentially mirror the same set of data an infinite amount of times in different configurations, persistently too in case a certain configuration got accessed more often than others. The layout of files on disk really isn't all that tied to the OS.

Comment: I should have specified "transparent compression". The data is compressed, but you don't have to care about it. Regarding the second, if you want RAM speed, you have to load it in RAM; if you want the data to persist after your process is finished, you have to write it to disk.

Comment: For Python, I really like PyTables. Some in-kernel search: http://pytables.github.io/usersguide/libref/structured_storage.html?highlight=where#tables.Table.where

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks for this, I'll have a look at in-kernel queries too.

Comment: "PyTables is built on top of the HDF5 library, using the Python language and the NumPy package"

Answer (score 0):

One factor to consider is performance of disk access. Using hd5f, everything is stored in continuous area of disk, making reading data faster with fewer disk seek and rotation. On the other hand, using file system to organize data may involve reading from many small files, thus more disk access is required.